Confusion regarding Cure of Varnasankar in Dharmasutra
I was searching a cure for Varnasankarata, & found an answer of Rickross on an already existing Question about it's remedy. There Rick quoted Gautama Dharmasutra highlighting that the Seventh Generation is cured from it. Then I read chapter 4 of Gautama and saw in the later verses that The pure laws aren't applicable for reverse marriages i.e. lower varna man with upper varna woman like shudra man with Vaishya woman. What ' pure laws' is this talking about, is this regarding cure of Varnasankar? Like Varnasankar can't be cured even in 7th gen of reverse marriage child?
And how does cure in 7th gen happen? Are there rules to follow till that what's the process?
I heard that the best way to cure varnasankarta is to be celibate whole life, & then you will be sent to Narak & a gain a new birth as a non sankar.
Please suggest the cures for Varnasankara if the Father is Shudra & Mother is Vaishya
